# Failed to save settings. Please restart PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

When working in PhpStorm version 2022.2 and 2022.2.1, the following error is always displayed to me.

> **Error**
>
> Failed to save settings. Please restart PhpStorm

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Instead of having "[FIXED]" in the question title, accept your own answer.

Comment: @LazyOne cant accept answer in 2 days

Comment: Yeah. You need more rep to be able to accept it sooner. I forgot about this moment. **P.S.** You may add "FIXED." into the actual answer if you think it will make it more obvious for others that this issue has been resolved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with ***PHP Annotation*** and ***Symfony support*** plugin.

By disabling them, everything works properly.

Comment: This is not a solution if we need Symfony support.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you can write the .idea directory (missing permission in WSL directory for exemple...)

Comment: This should be a comment or suggestion to the parent post rather than a solution answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried various solutions but didn't work.

At last, I removed/renamed the `.idea` directory of my project and then it worked.

I encountered this issue once I started Phpstorm as sudo/root user to update it.